# "mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (448x7 and 576x10)" while trying to perform Layer Wise relevance propagation

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am getting the following error message: "mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (448x7 and 576x10)".

I am trying to do Layer Wise Relevance Propagation according to this tutorial: https://giorgiomorales.github.io/Layer-wise-Relevance-Propagation-in-Pytorch/

Here is the NN class:

```
class Cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Cnn,self).__init__()
    
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
         nn.Conv2d(3,16,kernel_size=3, padding=0,stride=2),
         nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
         nn.ReLU(),
         nn.MaxPool2d(2)
       )
    
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(16,32, kernel_size=3, padding=0, stride=2),
          nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )
    
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size=3, padding=0, stride=2),
          nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.MaxPool2d(2)
       )
    
    
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3*3*64,10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10,2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    
    
    def forward(self,x):
    
       out = self.layer1(x)
       out = self.layer2(out)
       out = self.layer3(out)
       out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)
       out = self.relu(self.fc1(out))
       out = self.fc2(out)
       return out
```

I have used this to train a network to do binary classification, and am now trying to run Layer Wise Relevance Propagation on it. Here is the part of the LRP code where I am getting the error:

```
def LRP_individual(model, X, device):
   # Get the list of layers of the network
   layers = [module for module in model.modules() if not isinstance(module, torch.nn.Sequential)][1:]

   # Propagate the input
   L = len(layers)
   A = [X] + [X] * L # Create a list to store the activation produced by each layer

   for layer in range(L):
       A[layer + 1] = layers[layer].forward(A[layer])
    
  # Rest of the LRP function
```

I would be very grateful for an explanation or solution to this problem.

Edits:
Input shape is (224, 224)

The entire error message is here:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-57d34cdaa5e2> in <module>
----> 1 Rel = LRP_individual(model_s, image, device="cpu")

<ipython-input-84-447b67217029> in LRP_individual(model, X, device)
     19     #
     20         print(A[layer].data.shape)
---> 21         A[layer + 1] = layers[layer].forward(A[layer])
     22         print('666')
     23 

/mpcdf/soft/SLE_15/packages/skylake/pytorch/gpu-cuda-11.2/anaconda_3_2020.02-2020.02/1.8.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     92 
     93     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 94         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     95 
     96     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

/mpcdf/soft/SLE_15/packages/skylake/pytorch/gpu-cuda-11.2/anaconda_3_2020.02-2020.02/1.8.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1751     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1752         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1753     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1754 
   1755 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (448x7 and 576x10)
```

Comment: What is your input shape?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full backtrace that Python helpfully printed  in your console, and the code that lead tho the error. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited the question.